# How to check if the map and reduce operations are being done all nodes

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a cluster with 3 nodes , when I place my file in node1 it gets replicated to nodes 2 and 3.
This I am able to verify using the http://localhost:9870 and in browse filesystem.

And when I run the wordcount program how to check if the map and reduce operations are executed in nodes 1,2,3?

Is there anyway we can check this?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the YARN UI to see which nodes executed which tasks